# Latin characters in phpMyAdmin with UTF-8 collation

Tags: php, encoding, phpmyadmin, collation, utf-8

My website uses:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

And this meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I created my database and tables in phpMyAdmin making sure everything is set as utf8_unicode_ci (table, fields, database), even the connection collation.

When I insert some latin characters (accents, ñ and stuff like that) into the database using an standard form made in PHP, it works fine, I can display the saved data in my website no problem. But if I go to phpMyAdmin, all the latin characters are all messed up, something like Ã±Ã±Ã±.

If I try to fix that data in phpMyAdmin, then my website displays the data incorrectly, with weird symbols ���.

What in this world am I doing wrong? I've been trying to work this out for hours with no success.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Artefacto says, this could be a problem local to phpMyAdmin.

If phpMyAdmin is fine (i.e. set to UTF-8) and the data is still showing up weird, then look at whether your database *connection* using UTF-8 as well?

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")
```

(or whatever you use as a database library)
might help if it isn't.

Comment: Yeah, I ran the query but everything stays the same.

Comment: Pekka I was doing it all wrong. So, as soon as I instantiated my MySQL class I added a new line to run that query on every page and now everything works perfectly. Now, here comes another question: is it possible to set some sort of default so I don't need to run SET NAMES all the time?

Answer (score 1):

If phpMyAdmin is showing `Ã±Ã±Ã±` instead of `ñññ`, that's because it's interpreting a UTF-8 bytestream as ISO-8859-1. So your database contents are probably correct, phpMyAdmin is just showing them in a wrong manner.

I'm not familiar with the application, but you can force the browser to read the page as UTF-8 (typically View > Encoding > UTF-8).

Comment: I tried changing the Google Chrome and Firefox encoding to UTF-8 but it didn't work. phpMyAdmin is still displaying the weird symbols (yes, I restarted the browser).

Comment: @Danny this is a setting on phpMyAdmin's front page (the "language" setting. You pick language and encoding there.)

Comment: Ok I tried this in two servers, both behave the same. My phpMyAdmin home is set to MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8). I tried passing all the values in my form through utf8_decode() before the inserts and I can see everything ok in phpMyAdmin but not in my website, which means phpMyAdmin is the freaking problem. However, how come I can read data from a WordPress installation saved as UTF-8 and not the data saved from my own website?

Answer (score 1):

for Scuzzu's Question there are several ways:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/18/fixing-column-encoding-mess-in-mysql/

I would have eight more links with different tasks but this site is prevent me from saving them...

"as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink"

Answer (score 1):

**mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")** solved my problem.

Problem: Characters displayed correctly in phpMyAdmin, wrong in HTML/PHP. Characters: â, î, etc.

The headers are ok (utf8), phpmyadmin displays the content in the correct form, but the website keeps showing weird question-mark characters (inside a black diamond character).

HTML code:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Solution: I've added in php (preceding any other queries):

`mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`

Other causes can lead to this behaviour; this is only one part of the solution. You may need to check content-type, web server configuration (httpd.conf), html lang / dir, charset, etc. However, question mark in a black diamond seems to be more specific to this problem/solution, in other cases are displayed 2-3 weird characters instead of the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

After doing `mysql_query("SET names 'utf8';");`
You need also to go to mySQL and define collation as UTF-8, also!
This should solve your problem.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1- Edit file:

> my.ini (MsWindos)
>   
>     my.cnf (GNU/linux)

2- Look for [mysqld] entry and append:

```
  character-set-server = utf8
  skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

The whole view should look like:

```
[mysqld]
  port=3306
  character-set-server = utf8
  skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

3- Restart MySQL service!

Answer (score 0):

If phpMyAdmin is fine (i.e. set to UTF-8) and the data is still showing up weird, then look at whether your database connection using UTF-8 as well?

Just set `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` **after** `mysql_connect` line:

```
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggled with the same problem and finally found an elegant way to check and change collation via PHP function `mysqli_set_charset`. Following piece of code has to be included between a `$conn` check and an `$sql` query:

```
if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn)); //optional row
    die();
}
```

I found the solution here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php