# Characters not shown properly Visual Studio

Tags: c#, datagridview, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I made a database in PhpMyAdmin and developed an application in Visual Studio 2010 C#.

When I add a new row in PhpMyAdmin, special characters are shown in Visual Studio properly, but when I add it in datagridview in Visual Studio, the characters č, ć and đ are not shown properly in tables.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are those carrier displaying in datagridviews?  As non-accented characters, as @Dave suggests?  As HTML encoded entities?  Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved problem:** added to connectionString **charset=utf8**

```
connectionString="..... ;Default Command Timeout=300000; charset=utf8;"
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the collation on the database is set incorrectly as accent insensitive. This should help: [Latin characters in phpMyAdmin with UTF-8 collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977238/latin-characters-in-phpmyadmin-with-utf-8-collation)

Comment: But I already set collation to UTF-8 general_ci and it doesn't work :(